# simulating risc-v for rtems 5 bsp testing

Tags: riscv, rtems

How can I run RTEMS BSP tests for RISCV using a simulator?

I followed the RTEMS [quick start](https://docs.rtems.org/branches/master/user/start/index.html) guide for sparc/erc32.

In attempting to perform the BSP tests, I ran into the same problems highlighted in a separate [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58348878/rtems-5-bsp-test-failing), but followed the instructions in that response and was able to execute tests with the Software Instruction Simulator (SIS), as follows:

`rtems-test --rtems-bsp=erc32-sis --rtems-tools=$HOME/quick-start/rtems/5 .`

The [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58348878/rtems-5-bsp-test-failing) stated that the SIS also supports RISCV simulation.

I went through the installation instructions again for riscv/rv32i, but was not able to execute bsp tests with SIS.

`rtems-test --rtems-bsp=rv32i-sis --rtems-tools=$HOME/quick-start/rtems/5 .`

fails with the following:

`error: cannot find bsp configuration file: rv32i-sis.ini`

Looking in the directory with `erc32-sis.ini`, I only find riscv .ini files associated with spike.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in the rtems source directory, you will get the supported list of BSPs:

```
rtems-test --list-bsps
```